# How to combine selected sub-lists into one data frame in R?

Tags: r

Here's subset of 3 plant species that I am working with

```
spp <- c("Shorea robusta Gaertn.", "Schima wallichii (DC.) Korth.", 
"Terminalia alata Roth")
```

I want to retrieve occurrence data for these species from GBIF and I am using "rgbif::occ_data" function

```
library(rgbif)

test.rgbif <- occ_data(scientificName = spp, hasCoordinate=T, 
 geometry = "POLYGON ((78.0074716700000010 24.5425829399999991, 
  78.0074716700000010 32.2509633700000009, 
  90.2318328799999989 32.2509633700000009, 
  90.2318328799999989 24.5425829399999991, 
  78.0074716700000010 24.5425829399999991))")

test.rgbif # List of 3 each with List of 2


output <- bind_rows(test.rgbif$`Shorea robusta Gaertn.`$data,
 test.rgbif$`Schima wallichii (DC.) Korth.`$data,
 test.rgbif$`Terminalia alata Roth`$data); 

dim(output) 
#20      78
```

As is done above, I want to combine second sublists of 3 lists into one dataframe. But, this will be impractical to do in this fashion when I will be working with several species. So, could somebody please suggest me how can I do this by picking second sublists of 3 lists instead of giving their full names is done now?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `test.rgbif[, spp[1]] <- ...`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `do.call(rbind, ...)` routine:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(test.rgbif[spp], function(df) df$data))
```

If the `data.frame`s have different columns or column orders, `dplyr::bind_rows` is more suitable as it will match by column names:

```
do.call(bind_rows, lapply(test.rgbif[spp], function(df) df$data))
```

Comment: Thank you mt1022 for you helpful answer, as my data frames (sublists) have different dimensions, bind_rows fits better to my need than rbind i.e. do.call(bind_rows, lapply(test.rgbif[spp], function(df) df$data))

Comment: @R-enthusiast, Sure. `bind_rows` are more flexible for input data.frames. I never use rgbif, so I really do not known how the real data like.

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it* but the following should do it

```
library(magrittr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)

test.rgbif %>% 
  # turns list of length 3 with 2 elements each into a 
  # list of 2 with 3 elements each
  purrr::transpose %>%
  # take the data list-entry
  .$data %>% 
  # and rbind its 3 elements
  rbindlist(idcol = "Species")
```

*: I get the following error

```
> test.rgbif <- ...
Error in check_wkt(geometry) : 
  bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target at '
' in 'polygon ((78.0074716700000010 24.5425829399999991, 
                       78.0074716700000010 32.25'
```

Comment: Dear user22966153, I don't know why you are receiving that error, but it is just WKT file to define the extent of my area of interest. Anyways, thank you for your answer. As you answer involves installing new packages, I will stick to mt1022's answer for this time which is straight forward.